How to go to the start of the latest command in the terminal in VS Code?
I am in Visual Studio Code doing some web scraping with BeautifulSoup. The HTML content is being shown in the terminal.
The issue is that it is too long and, to go to the beginning of the execution command, I have to use my eyes and scroll up the page with the mouse to find the beginning. Is there a way to go to the command line directly? I would also accept a solution that creates a new terminal every time I execute a commande, so that the beginning of the command would be the beginning of the terminal.
I have used the shortcuts like "Scroll To Previous Command" but it directs me at the beginning of the first command in the terminal (at the very beginning of the terminal).

Scroll to Previous Command should be doing what you want.  What terminal shell are you using?  And what OS?

I am using a Python Shell, i am adding the screenshot to the description of my issue. Scroll to previous command goes directly at the beginning of the terminal :/

It may be because shell integration isn't working in your environment - but I think Powershell integration is supposed to be supported on Windows.  You might also show your "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows" setting contents, maybe others will spot something.  Also have you tried git bash?  It works for me there.
